# C3 and React - DOMException

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, c3.js

I'm trying to use C3 to render a chart in my React project.

## The problem

What I do is dynamically generate an id (UUID) and attach it to a `div` in my chart component. I then call some code after the component has rendered in `componentDidMount`. This is a common pattern, I have seen it in other projects.

At first, everything seemed fine. However, after repeatedly refreshing the page, sometimes the chart generation does not work. The error I get is:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#a-really-long-id' is not a valid selector.
```

## What I tried

I tried using `setTimeout` to delay when the chart was attached, but curiously I still got the same result, even after a 10 second delay. This leads me to believe that this is not a race condition, and caused by something else. Maybe C3 reads the DOM once and does not respond to changes? But that would not explain why it works *sometimes...*

Even trying to select the element by id from the Chrome developer console did not work.

[image]

## Code

Here is my full component code:

```
// assets/js/index.jsx
import React from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';
import c3 from 'c3';


class Chart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.id = uuid();
        this._update = this._update.bind(this);
    }

    _update() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        this.chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: `#${this.id}`,
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['Male', 0],
                    ['Female', 0],
                    ['Brand', 0]
                ],
                type: 'bar',
                colors: {
                    Male: '#0066CC',
                    Female: '#FF6666',
                    Brand: '#808080'
                },
                groups: [
                    ['Male', 'Female', 'Brand']
                ],
                order: null
            },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.3
                }
            },
            transition: {
                duration: 500
            },
            tooltip: {
                show: false
            },
            axis: {
                x: { show: false },
                y: { show: false },
            },
            size: { width: 220, height: 320 },
            grid: {
                x: { show: false }
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            this.chart.load({
                columns: [
                    ['Male', data.male],
                    ['Female', data.female],
                    ['Brand', data.brand]
                ]
            });
        }, 500);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._update();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={this.id} className="chart"></div>
        );
    }
}


export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be added as a comment, but since its big, adding it as an answer.

Are you using html4/ html5 semantics?

As per HTML4 (https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"),  colons (":"), and periods (".").

As per HTML5 (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html)

> When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique
>   amongst all the IDs in the element’s tree and must contain at least
>   one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

Your uuid might be generating a valid Id sometimes and sometimes it might not (not sure how uuid works)

If you are not using HTML5 semantics, you can simply add `<!DOCTYPE html>`

at the top of your html document and give a try.

Also,

You used settimeout in your logic and within that you used this.Chart

`this`, now will refer to settimeout rather than the class.

Can you try changing

```
setTimeout(function() {
        this.chart.load({
            columns: [
                ['Male', data.male],
                ['Female', data.female],
                ['Brand', data.brand]
            ]
        });
    }, 500);
```

to

```
  setTimeout( () => {
        this.chart.load({
            columns: [
                ['Male', data.male],
                ['Female', data.female],
                ['Brand', data.brand]
            ]
        });
    }, 500);
```

Comment: I think this is the answer. I will confirm it here in a few hours.

Comment: This was the issue. It was trivial to prepend a string to the front of the uuid to satisfy the naming format.